# How to loop through every folder of url in PHP

Tags: php

Suppose I have a URL as -

**http://localhost/wordpress/index.php/solutions/**

and if I use `echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];`

It will give the output as `/wordpress/index.php/solutions/`

Is there any buit-in function in PHP that will allow me to **echo** the name of each folder in the URL?

Like

- wordpress
- index.php
- solutions

I need the above names ahead in the program

Comment: Can you not just explode the url into an array and loop through that?

Comment: [`explode`](http://php.net/explode])`('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`

Comment: Ah thanks! Just couldn't recollect this method!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the function `explode` like so:

```
$paths = explode("/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
$paths = array_values(array_filter($paths)); // Filter out the empty first row
```

Then you can access them by index like this:

```
$wordpress = $paths[0]; // "wordpress"
```

If you do *not* want the querystring included you should filter them out as **a1111exe** mentioned:

```
$paths = explode("/", preg_replace("/\?.*$/", "", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))
$paths = array_values(array_filter($paths));
```

Comment: As I recall, `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` may contain query string for GET requests. In this case it may be useful to replace the query string, e.g.: `explode('/', preg_replace('/\?.*$/', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']))`

Comment: @a1111exe Have you tested the regular expression? If it works I will add it in my answer

Comment: Yes, here is a working example:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bc4c2b7816c9bd806398f0d9f5dd2abc7e7cac6c

Comment: Btw, it seems, that if the start of a subject string is a delimiter itself, the 0-indexed element of the resulting array  will be empty. To prevent this: `array_values(array_filter(explode(...`

Comment: A new example: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/c3d61ef15909d9be46038b9a6494396e13dcf9cd

Comment: @a1111exe Good you noticed, I'll include it in my answer, thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Check this out as well:

```
<?php
$url = 'http://username:password@hostname:9090/path?arg=value#anchor';

var_dump(parse_url($url));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_SCHEME));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_USER));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PASS));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PORT));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY));
var_dump(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_FRAGMENT));
?>
```

Then above array with the key `path` is what you're looking for.